# Переназначить юнит, как основной/первый в C++ Builder 2010

Tags: c++builder

Начну с того, что использую Builder 2010. Ситуация такая - делал прогу, так получилось, что основной программой с GUI был Unit3.cpp, а вылезающее окошко с определенным сообщением, тоже нарисованное мною, было как Unit1.cpp. Но при запуске программы было тем не менее всё нормально, сначала загружалась оболочка из Unit3, а потом при нажатии на кнопку, выскакивало сообщение из Unit1. Решил я это всё дело переименовать. Переименовал: Unit3.cpp стал main.cpp, Unit1.cpp стал message.cpp. В то время, когда я решил переименовать, моя прога не работала из-за некоторых недописанных функций, и плюс к тому же при загрузке проекта, первым стал загружаться message.cpp. Я не придал этому особо значения. Но потом когда доделал функции и смог запустить прогу, к моему удивлению при запуске вылезло окошко не из main, а из message. Собственно вопрос - где и как в билдере указать, что у меня main - это основное окно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел сам:) Что бы выбрать главную форму, нужно выбрать её в выпадающем списке в Project -> Options... -> Forms.
Вопрос [**ЗАКРЫТ**]